# python requests not able to make connection to NSE india, Connection error

Tags: python, python-requests, connection

import requests

x = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm' )

print(x.status_code)

print(x.content)

Giving connection error. Please help how to correct it.

Comment: I am using VS code IDE.

Comment: You could try with a proxy/user agent combinations but I think it's fair to assume they are not too keen on being scraped.

Comment: If you want those data, try use `Selenium` to click the download in csv button.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import requests

url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
                         'like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36',
           'accept-language': 'en,gu;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8', 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'}
session = requests.Session()
request = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5)
cookies = dict(request.cookies)
response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.content)
```

This code for the first time you try to access the website in your program, If your accessing the site multiple times then use this:
`response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5, cookies=cookies)` everytime you try to access again.
Tell me if this works

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more, I keep getting  Read timed out

Comment: Does this not work on the first run or it stops after a while?

Comment: I noticed that nseindia is somehow blacklisting requests based on IP address, the above code works well for IPs based in India and I get read time out for US and Europian IPs. What's weird is that when I use a browser to visit nseindia it works for all IPs regardless. I will check if a solution based on selenium works well for all IPs

Comment: I guess the nse site blocks selenium chrome driver

Answer (score 0):

Try add user agent to header:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.162 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get('https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm', headers=headers)
print(r.content)
```